# how to include versioned JS files in data-main attribute in require js

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am trying to include JS file with version using require js like below:

```
<script data-main="main.57302bdda2413911ef49e5d48c63d777.js" 
    src="/etc/ui/iea/clientlibs/core/require/js/require.js">
</script>
```

> **Console Error:** require.js:1 Uncaught Error: No define call for
>   main.57302bdda2413911ef49e5d48c63d777

Is there any syntax error here? 
How to include the file with 2 dots in data-main attribute?

Comment: What happens when you drop `.js` from the name you give to `data-main`?

Comment: Tried that too, it is not working. Problem is, I need the syntax to load the file with 2 dots (like jquery.min.js)

Comment: How is it not working? What happens? Edit your question with the information. `data-main` is not special. It is exactly the same as putting the module name you put there in a `require` call or in the list of dependencies of a `define` call. I've got large projects that have module and file names with multiple dots in them. No problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the r.js optimizer's [build config](https://github.com/requirejs/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js) if you are using a **name** property, it will use that name to include a module by the same name in your bundled file somewhere like this:

```
}), define("main", ["app"], function(a) {
    a.on("before:start", function() {}), a.on("start", function(a) {}), a.on("application:ready", function() {
        a.start()
    })
})
```

When this bundled file coupled with this define definition is renamed as main.*.js instead of main.js, it throws an error

> require.js:1 Uncaught Error: No define call for main.*.js

because it couldn't find that module named define call, because instead it has main.js's define call, as explained.

If I could understand / take a hint from your question correctly, you want a range of files perhaps using a regex, which requirejs should understand that if they exist should take the value of that **name** property. I do not know the solution to this problem, I'd like to know if anyone does, would be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any way to compare the module name using regular expression?

Comment: An ugly looking, but a valid fix is this (thanks to @VidhyaMahendran and her Husband for this) :

` require.config({
                paths: {
                    'main': // path to the url of your main.*.js file made
                }
            });`

Since if require.config is written in multiple instances, it essentially gets merged, this works.
added just after requirejs is loaded

Answer (score 0):

In Your case file `main.xxxx.js` must be in (http) root directory.

Instead of `file:///home/..../index.html` use static http server ([list](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255))

Replace `/etc/ui/..../require.js` with `require.js`. Place `main.xxxx.js` and `require.js` in the same directory. Run http server in this directory. Go to `http://127.0.0.1:xxxx`